# Scraping Data from Webpage using BeautifulSoup returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new at this..
For example, I'm trying to scrape something like this (number 24)

```
<td class="score part"> <span class="p1_home>24</span></td>
```

[image: What to scrape?]

but my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get("http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/jLRSI3m9/#detalji")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')

data2 = soup.find('td',{'class':'score part'})

print(data2)
```

[image: Output]

gives me none

Where was I wrong?

Comment: The problem is that the webpage only loads the data into an Ajax Table. One example for a question is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913280/beautifulsoup-and-ajax-table-problem

Comment: I suggest marking this as a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678485/scrape-with-beautifulsoup-from-site-that-uses-ajax-pagination-using-python

Answer (score 0):

You had the idea right but this website, I think, implemented some kind of javascript to hide values so as to deter people like you from scraping their website.  Try using selenium as it can scrape a website as a person would see it.  Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You can see what I'm talking about.  If you right click and choose 'view source', you cannot find the value that you're referring to.  You can see it when you inspect elements.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, thank you for your help

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/jLRSI3m9/#detalji")

posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("p1_home")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
```